# windows server 2022 vpn service set up and works properly, but clients cannot connect to it

Tags: windows, vpn, remote-desktop, l2tp, windows-server-2022

I have a VPS with Windows server 2022 standard, I set up a VPN service in routing and remoting part in the service manager.

The service is running correctly (according to remote monitoring), but when I try to connect to its VPN from my windows 10, it cannot connect and this error shows up:

[image]

I used l2tp connection and my username and password and also Pre-shared Key is correct

I can remote access with a remote desktop without any problem.

Comment: Have you enabled Microsoft-CHAP Version 2?

Comment: yes, I did, still not working, any idea how to check the VPN server itself, I cannot connect on my other devices too, including android, is there any website where I could enter authentication and try to connect to my VPN server?